# Navigation intent that would work with maps and waze

Tags: android, android-intent, android-navigation

I'm trying to start a navigation activity with an intent from my app. I want it to start navigation from my location to a point that I provide. I've tried this way

```
String uri = "geo: "+String.valueOf(latitude) + "," + String.valueOf(longitude);
context.startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse(uri)));
```

It works great when I choose to navigate with `Waze` (it starts with the "start navigation" dialog right away), but doesnt work with `maps` (only shows the point, not the navigation option)
If I use this way

```
Intent intent = 
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?"  + 
                            "&daddr=" + String.valueOf(latitude) + "," 
                             + String.valueOf(longitude)));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Its the opposite, starting the navigation with `maps` and only showing the point with `Waze`

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've done this myself and have had no issues using it the following way:

```
intent.setData(Uri.parse("geo:" + getLatitude() + "," + 
    getLongitude() + "?q=" + getStreet() + "+" + 
    getHousenumber() + "+" + getPostalcode() + "+" + 
    getCity()));
```

The difference is that I use "&q=" for the query as stated by Google.

**See:**
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

Comment: I don't have the address of the place, but I've added the lat and lon to the q string and it worked!

Comment: String uri = "geo:0,0?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude;
startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));

Comment: it doesn't has to be address btw, you could just pass name of the POI, or follow what RCB and Avi Cohen says if you doesn't

Comment: navigation doesn't start with the Google Map.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say anything about navigation. It says "Show a location on a map".

Answer (score 11):

This is a simple way and works on both of them:

Java

```
String uri = "geo:?q= latitude,longtitude";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

Kotlin

```
val uri = "geo:?q=$latitude,$longtitude"
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)))
```

I hope this will be useful

Comment: perfect this is the best soloution  for ever bro ...

damet garm

Comment: You don't need more than: startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:?q="+ latitude + "," + longitude)));

Answer (score -4):

ok Google maps

```
    final String uri="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&hl=de&geocode=&saddr=" + Global.lattaxi + "," + Global.lontaxi + "&daddr=" + Global.latcliente + "," + Global.loncliente + "&ie=UTF8";
     final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
            "com.google.android.apps.maps",
            "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Write you answer in english

Comment: I don't think it's much better in English. Maybe you should read the question more carefully.